# Alias to watch a log and replace some characters in output

Tags: sed, pipe, watch

I need to create an alias in .bashrc to print the last ten lines of a log every 1000 seconds and replace some characters (every "\s" with a single space) in the output.

I am combining two different aliases:

```
alias watch10='watch '

alias dcr='-n 1000 \'tail -10  some.log | sed "s/\\s/\ /g"\''
```

After adding the aliases to .bashrc, I run "source .bashrc" and I get no error.

The log lines look like this:

```
somestuff /B/R/Joe\sPaul\s-\sMike\s-\sSteve
```

I want the output lines to be:

```
somestuff /B/R/Joe Paul - Mike - Steve
```

I call the command in ssh by combining the two aliases:

```
watch10 dcr
```

This produces an error:

```
sh: 1: dcr: not found
```

What is the solution?

Note that it works when I use this alias (instead of dcr) which does not attempt to replace the annoying "\s" with single spaces:

```
alias dc="-n 1000 'tail -10  some.log'"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest single quotes even if you escape it with a backslash.

A workaround will be:

- Once close the substring with a single quote.
- Put `\'` which represents a literal single quote.
- Then restart remaining substring with a single quote.

As an example, you can print "That's it." with:

```
echo 'That'\''s it.'
```

Needless to say it will be easier to surround the whole string with
double quotes if applicable.

Going back to your issue, please try:

```
alias dcr='-n 1000 '\''tail -10 some.log | sed "s/\\\s/ /g"'\'
```

Note that you need another backslash to escape `\s`.

But why don't you merge the two aliases into one as:

```
alias dcr='watch -n 1000 '\''tail -10 some.log | sed "s/\\\s/ /g"'\'
```

(There may be some specific reasons...)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your two suggestions work perfectly (with and without merging the aliasases). I knew it had someting to do with the quotes, but I did not know enough to figure it out by myself.

Comment: I also figured out why I was getting the "dcr not found" error. I am working with tmux and I was updating .bashrc in one window and running the alias in another. The second window was just ignoring the changes. It worked when I did everything in the same window.

Comment: @AndreArseneault Good to know it helped. I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to concatenate aliases. Aliases substitution is only performed on the first token of a simple command. When you type 'alias1 alias2', assuming alias1=cmd1 alias2=cmd, the code will execute 'cmd1 alias2' (alias2 assume to be literal argument).

The question make few assumptions, which I could not verify on Mint19

- Placing the the 2 aliases (watch10, dcr) into .bashrc works: Mint19 produces 'unterminated quoted string`).
- Likewise setting dc to '-n 1000 'tail -10  some.log'" and using it with 'watch10 dc' works. I believe this will result in running the 'dc' (/usr/bin/dc) program (basic calculator), and not the taking the dc options.

Few options:

If you want the 'dcr' command to be used from other programs (`watch` in this case), write a small script, and place it in a personal folder that is referenced in the PATH (e.g. ~/bin). Note that using a script will simplify the process of setting up the '\s' replacement.

Alternative is to create combine 'wdcr' alias, combined to 'watch -n 1000 \'tail -10 some.log ...`.

- Running over ssh

When you run '.ssh' the remote host with a command, it is consider as login session, and not interactive session,. It will source '~/.bash_profile'. Unless the profile script is rferencing ~/.bashrc, you will not get aliases in the remote session.

Also note that bash strongly discourage aliases for anything but interactive sessions, in favor of functions.

Comment: All I can say is that I am running raspbian and combining both aliases (watch10 and dc) works fine. Based on tshiono's suggestion, I will now be using the single merged alias.